# MPMoviePlayer: Show volume slider on iPad

Tags: iphone, ios, mpmovieplayer

Hi My name is abhishek and I am trying to use the mpmovieplayer to show a video in my app. I created a sample app and I can see the play/ pause , next, previous control. However I cannot see the volume slider. Does the volume slider not appear by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking at the documentation, it seems MPMoviePlayerController may not include a volume slider anymore.  Perhaps look into using an [MPVolumeView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPVolumeView_Class/Reference/Reference.html).